# Resource differences

Tags: cpu, cooling

I have an Asus T100 that does nothing but run ie 11 in three tabs for different dvr camera systems.  The little Atom is a Z3735 quad core Bay Trail only gets half stressed if I push all 18 camera feeds to their highest resolution.  I dumped some soda on it and while cleaning it up (full disassembly) I put the same task to a newer Yoga with 12 GB ram and an eighth gen i7.  While the Yoga had no real trouble it ran HOT enough I had to take it apart to check the thermals.  Everything is fine, but why is an i7-8550u running at 175F doing the same task with the same settings on the same OS that the atom does at 120F?  Additionally, both were running the same external monitor with their lids closed....

Answer (score 1):

8550u has 15w TDP, Z3735E has 2.2w TDP. Even if the workload is the same, 8550u is designed to consume (and expend as heat) 7x the power of the Atom.

Comment: This is true, and the atom uses passive cooling. But my 5690s eat 130 watts but rarely get over 60 degrees.Is it just the cooling solution that is lacking?  Does ie use more resources if they are available??  I do not think that three tabs open in ie should be such a burden on the laptop when a much lesser machine doesn't break a sweat.  What am I missing??

Comment: You have not specified the cpu load of your workload.